# Three.JS how to use ray casters with multiple cameras?

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I'm hoping someone here has done this before.  I have a ThreeJS scene, which is essentially a cube.  The cube has 6 images one on each of the scenes, basically rendering a 360 panoramic photo.

Within our 3D space, we have 6 cameras, one each pointing at each of the directions, forward, backward, left, right, up, and down.  Basically we want to be able to project each of these views all at once.

So, to do this I've made 6 cameras, and added them to the scene.  In the scene, we have clickable targets.  I want to be able to use ray caster to register a click in any camera view.  For example, this is what it looks like:

[image: a]

Within our scene we have clickable hot spots.  I want to be able to click on a hotspot on ANY of the 6 cameras.  But, I can't get the ray caster to work on even one.  This is the code I am using:

```
if (this._my_cameras && this._my_cameras[0])
        {
            var mouse = {};
    
            mouse.x = ( this._nextMouseX / this._my_cameras[0].viewport.width ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - ( this._nextMouseY / this._my_cameras[0].viewport.height ) * 2 + 1;
    
            
            Object.assign(
                this._mouse,
                coords.normalizeScreenXY(mouse, this._my_cameras[0].viewport)
            );
    
            console.log("this._mouse: " + util.inspect(this._mouse));
    
            this._raycaster.setFromCamera(this._mouse, this._my_cameras[0]);
            
        }
        else
        {
            this._raycaster.setFromCamera(this._mouse, this._camera);
        }
        
        let intersections = this._raycaster.intersectObjects(
            this._scene.children,
            true
        );
```

this._nextMouseX / Y are the raw mouse coordinates on screen.  My normalize function should normally the mouse coordinates to -1 to 1 as needed.  This all works fine if I have one camera taking up the whole view.  But with 6 cameras, I never get a ray caster intersection with my targets.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get raycasting or object picking working across multiple cameras?

Edit 1:

This is the code I am now trying to get to work using viewports for the cameras for the raycasting:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this._igloo_cameras.length; i++)
            {
                this._mouse.x = ( this._nextMouseX / this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport.w ) * 2 - 1;
                this._mouse.y = -1 * (this._nextMouseY  / this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport.z)  * 2 + 1;
    
                console.log("this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport: " + util.inspect(this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport));
                console.log("Igloo Camera #" + i + " this._mouse: " + util.inspect(this._mouse));
        
                this._raycaster.setFromCamera(this._mouse, this._igloo_cameras[i]);
    
                let intersections = this._raycaster.intersectObjects(
                    this._scene.children,
                    true
                );
                
                all_intersections.push(...intersections);
            }
```

with this I get mouse values outside of 1 to -1 and I still don't get accurate click locations/targets.

This is what I get in my console:

```
this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport: { x: 0, y: 685, z: 685, w: 685 }
Viewer3D.js:521 Igloo Camera #0 this._mouse: { x: -0.5883211678832116,
  y: -1.3649635036496353,
  rawX: 141,
  rawY: 810 }
Viewer3D.js:520 this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport: { x: 685, y: 685, z: 685, w: 685 }
Viewer3D.js:521 Igloo Camera #1 this._mouse: { x: -0.5883211678832116,
  y: -1.3649635036496353,
  rawX: 141,
  rawY: 810 }
```

Comment: You're going to have to modify your `mouse.x` calculations so it goes from `[-1, 1]` six times as you cross the screen from left -> right. When you're all the way on the left, you'll have to do `.setFromCamera()` using `myCameras[0]`, then the next square over, you'll have to set the next camera `myCameras[1]`, then `myCameras[2]`, and so on, until you're setting the 6th camera all the way to the right.

Comment: OK - so you are saying I need to normalize the mouse to the viewport of each camera, or to the overall screen?  I've tried both approaches and neither has worked so far.

Comment: Yes, you need to normalize the mouse to the viewport of each camera, then use that camera when raycasting on that 1/6th of the screen. Using the overall screen won't help you because you have squeezed 6 cameras into it. You say you've tried both approaches, but I don't see it in your code sample above.

Comment: @Marquizzo I just posted a sample of what I tried using viewports.  That produces mouse values out of the desired range (-1 to 1), and does not find clicks using any camera that are accurate.  Any thoughts or am I missing something?

Comment: Your x calculation looks good, but the y calculation looks wrong.  I guess you are trying to compensate for the switch in direction of the y axis.  But I'd suggest:

this._mouse.y = -1 * ((this._nextMouseY  / this._igloo_cameras[i].viewport.z)  * 2 - 1);

This will give 0.635 for y=125 (i.e. 810 - 685).
(and -1 for y = 685, +1 for y = 0)